# neo4j Create node with properties or Set node properties if node is exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create new node and update node based on property where if node is already exists ,  my query is creating node properly but updating the node properties when node is already exists , below is my cypher query

```
MERGE (n:CourseCluster {mysql_coursecluster_id:"2"})
ON CREATE SET n.Name = "pavan", n.Comments = "pavan reddy" return n
```

Comment: Don't quite understand what you want to do here. Maybe add an example.

Comment: the above query is  creating node properly , but its not updating the properties when node is already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two clauses you can use with `MERGE`, respectively :

- `ON CREATE` : performs actions when the node is created
- `ON MATCH` : performs actions when the node already exist

in your case :

```
MERGE (n:CourseCluster {mysql_coursecluster_id:"2"})
ON CREATE SET n.Name = "pavan", n.Comments = "pavan reddy"
ON MATCH SET n.Name = "pavan", n.Comments = "other comment"
```

if there are no differences of properties to be set between `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH`, you can just omit them :

```
MERGE (n:CourseCluster {mysql_coursecluster_id:"2"})
SET n.xx = ...
```